# Django URL using javascript to get client end information

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, url

My problem that I am trying to resolve is that I made an Ajax-autocorrect input feature and "onclick" of a button I get the value inside that input and attempt to make the page redirect to a Django URL.

Here is the URL inside my url.py file:

```
    url(r'^groups/add-member/(?:/(?P<pk_group>[-\w]+))?/(?:/(?P<pk_member>[-\w]+))?/$', views.add_member, name='add-member')
```

inside the HTML I have this script:

```
<script>
function add_member(id){
  var input=document.getElementById("myText").value
  console.log(id)   //Correctly gets ID #  
  console.log(input)   //Correctly gets the name (string) of member instance

  url = "{% url 'add-member' 0 zzzz %}".replace('0', id).replace('zzzz',input);

}
</script>
```

And the resulting error that I get is:

```
Reverse for 'add-member' with arguments '(0, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['flexfeed/groups/add-member/(?:/(?P<pk_group>[-\\w]+))?/(?:/(?P<pk_member>[-\\w]+))?/$']
```

I'm having trouble understanding my error. If anyone could suggest how to fix this issue or possibly suggest a difdferent approach to this particular problem I'd really appreciate it!

The end goal is that I want my page to redirect to my update view at the correct link!

Comment: Does your url work if you put it into the browser? I'm guessing yes, but just want to check.

Comment: It does! (Not the default 0 and 'zzzz' those were just place holders. But with the right combination it works fine!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there is a problem with the order of what's happening. When Django renders your template it processes the tags. This happens before any javascript is called.

So you are trying to call the url with 0 and zzzz as the arguments. Django tries to fetch this and because the second argument is an empty variable here it doesn't match anything.

I would fix this by calling the url with two variables that are valid, then changing them with javascript.

```
    url = "{% url 'add-member' 0 'change-team' %}";
    url = url.replace(0, id).replace('change-team', input);
```

You might also be able to just put quotation marks around the zzzz.

Comment: Interestingly putting the 'zzzz' in quotes and leaving the zero as is worked fine! I just had to put the 'zzzz' in quotes which you helped guide me towards! Although I am a bit curious as to why that is... I have a solution now but i'm still curious why the page was rendering it as an error!

Comment: When the template is rendered by django it processes the tags. Your tag looked like it had zzzz as a python variable which evaluated to null. You don't have an url that matches the name "add-member" with an int argument and a null argument, so it threw an error.